# SHGetKnownFolderPath was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, winapi, known-folders

I've been studying Java-programming for about 7 months now and I've become interested in c++. I'm currently reading a c++ book too.

I'm using eclipse c++ since I'm pretty familiar with eclipse.

I have made like 6 projects (small ones) in c++ and everything has worked fine until now.

My problem is that I can not get the SHGetKnownFolderPath method to work.
The complete line is red , eventhough I have imported everything, build it, tried to run it. I have checked on internet sites and I've used the same code as other people has, but still not working for me.

It says: Function SHGetKnownFolderPath could not be resolved

I'm on a windows 8 computer 64 bit.
Here is the code:
**UPDATE**

```
    #define WINVER 0x0600 // 0x06020000  0x06030000
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <combaseapi.h>
#include <comutil.h> //for _bstr_t (used in the string conversion)
#include <knownfolders.h>
#include <winerror.h> //for HRESULT
#include <winnt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>






using namespace std;

int main(){

    LPWSTR wszPath = NULL;
    HRESULT hr;

    hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &wszPath);// THIS LINE IS COMPLETELY RED

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)){
    _bstr_t bstrPath(wszPath);
    std::string strPath((char*)bstrPath);
    std::cout << strPath;
    }

    CoTaskMemFree(wszPath);

return 0;
}
```

Here is the log:

```
     #pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw")
 ^
..\src\HelloWorld.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\src\HelloWorld.cpp:21:64: error: 'SHGetKnownFolderPath' was not declared in this scope
 hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &wszPath);
```

There is a little arrow pointing at the last parenthesis under &wszPath)

What could possibly be wrong?
I will be grateful for all answers or hints that I could get.

Comment: What is your Windows version definition? Maybe, you're trying to build your app for versions older than Vista? Do you have anything related to WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT macros in your build setup?

Comment: I just added #define WINVER 0x0600 .

Comment: "It says: Function SHGetKnownFolderPath could not be resolved", and "'SHGetKnownFolderPath' was not declared in this scope". Which of the two error messages is correct?

Comment: When I hold the mouse over SHGetKnownFolderPath it says it can't be resolved. When i hold mouse over the parameters on the method, it says not declared in this scope. but the error message points at the last parenthese under &wszPath. and log says Main.cpp:20:65: error: 'SHGetKnownFolderPath' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @jad I guess one is from eclipse and one from the real compiler. Both are correct just different wording.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing wrong with Eclipse, it is correctly processing the error output from the compiler.

Nothing wrong with the compiler, it is correctly complaining about an attempt to use a function without a preceding declaration.

[The official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) clearly tells you where to get that declaration:

[image]

Since this function requires Vista or later, you'll also need to follow the instructions at [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745.aspx#macros_for_conditional_declarations) for setting compatibility with a particular Windows version.

```
#define WINVER 0x0600
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
```

Once you fix your includes (not imports!  C++ is not Java.) you'll then discover that having the ability to cast does not make type safety issues go away.  This code is horribly broken:

```
_bstr_t bstrPath(wszPath);
std::string strPath((char*)bstrPath);
```

Casting a UTF-16 string to `char*` does not get you an ASCII string.  You can either use `wcout` which understands UTF-16, or call `WideCharToMultiByte` to get an ASCII string that `cout` can accept.

Comment: I included #include <shlobj.h> but stills shows error

Comment: @Johan: What have you defined `WINVER` to?  That same documentation section tells you this function is available starting in Vista, so if you have configured compatibility with XP, it won't be found.

Comment: I didn't define WINVER but I did now, built the project and still the same.

Comment: Do I have to add something in Library path in project properties or something?

Comment: No but you have to include windows.h in order to use any of the other headers.

Comment: Ok, but I have updated the code now, I forgot winver before. But what is wrong now? I press save, then build project, and still line is red.

Comment: Try shlobj.h after windows.h

Comment: Tried that now, still the same error: ain.cpp:20:65: error: 'SHGetKnownFolderPath' was not declared in this scope. And there is an arrow pointing at the last parenthese under &wszPath)

Comment: Are you using the official headers from Microsoft?

Comment: What do you mean with official headers? :P

Comment: The ones that come with the Windows SDK

Comment: I dont know I followed a tutorial on youtube how to set up eclipse with compiler and stuff. Maybe I should start from beginning

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you're using `WINVER`, when you should be using `_WIN32_WINNT`. `WINVER` mainly only affects very old features -- you'll generally want to define them both.

```
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
```

Comment: Ok i got new error message now saying : 17:09:21 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project testing ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\HelloWorld.o" "..\\src\\HelloWorld.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\Users\\Johan\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32" -o testing.exe "src\\HelloWorld.o" -lshell32.dll 
c:/users/johan/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32.dll
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

17:09:25 Build Finished (took 3s.297ms)

Comment: That's a linker error. You probably want to just use `-lshell32` but you'd have to look at your libraries to know for sure.

Comment: Do i have to include something in libraries in project properties or what ? :P

Comment: Sounds like you need to read some basic documentation on your IDE/compiler.

Comment: Yeah i guess. c++ feels more complicated than java. Thanks for helping me anyway!